# How to choose to install all apps at once in katoolin/Kali linux repositories interface?

Tags: scripts, metasploit, katoolin

How can I install all the Kali linux tools at once? This is what I have.

[image]
<sup>**View the categories of available software in katoolin interface**</sup>

Can I just press 0 for everything to be installed at once, without going into one category at a time when installing?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Kali is not supported in this forum, but I would suggest you just try pressing `0`. If that doesn't work you could modify the script or copy/paste the corresponding commands in a new script and execute that.

Comment: @KevInski may be trying to install Kali tools in Ubuntu (katoolin)

Comment: @Zanna Well, that is correct. I did not think of that.

Comment: is it me or does the screen actually say "or press (0) to install all"?

Comment: That's what the screen says, but it's kind of like a vending machine that doesn't give you your can of soft drink due to possibly missing packages.

Comment: thanks guys . I've got it working now. this is a very helpful community. sorry for the late reply btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I just press 0 for everything to be installed at once, without going into one category at a time when installing?

It probably won't work because a lot of the requested packages can't be found, so you'll have to do it the hard way.

> Press 0 to install all Kali linux tools.
>
> When you go to *View Categories* and then enter 0 for all, the installer will immediately return to where you were. Scroll up, and you'll see that a number of the packages can't be found. Those packages are no longer maintained or have been removed from the Kali repositories. Even with this issue, you'll still find a lot of the Kali software available for installation.
>
> So the best option is to install Kali linux tools in a series of distinct steps. Just like if you want to install Forensic tools on your system, then choose its option from the category and then type 0 to install all forensics tools.

[image]

> If you wish to go back to the main menu, type `gohome` in your katoolin interface. Now select the option 3 or 4 to install either the classicmenu indicator or the Kali menu. Press the <kbd>y</kbd> key to continue and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start its setup.
>
> Once you are done with installation of Kali tools using katoolin, you can quit by pressing the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and you will see the goodbye message.
>
> `shutdown requested....Goodbye...`

Credit for the tutorial goes to Kashif.

#### Warning about updates after installing Kali linux tools

The [LionSec Katoolin GitHub](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin) webpage clearly warns Katoolin users to be careful when updating software.

> Before updating your system, please remove all Kali-linux repositories to avoid any kind of problem.

[image: enter imageterminal an description here]

All kinds of problems can occur if you don't do this.

<sub>**Source:** [How To Install Kali Linux Tools On Ubuntu 16 And CentOS 7](http://linuxpitstop.com/install-kali-linux-tools-on-ubuntu-and-centos/)</sub>